# How to create Custom list for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-lists

I would like to create a cutomlistview for my fragment, I am a beginner please you can write me the appropriate code to view my list.

CustomListAdapter is colored red and I have to create a CustomListAdapter class I already try but I can not do it then if you can help me, I still have to do that to finish my project

Here is my code

```
public class listadmin extends Fragment {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
private ListView mMyListView;
private listadmin MyListAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listadmin, container, false);
    mMyListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListViewadmin);

    //create an ArrayList of a custom data class that you can create to hold the Admin Data
    ArrayList<CustomObjectClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //Now you need to get the data
    Cursor data = myDb.getAllAdmin();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(new CustomObjectClass(data.getString(1), data.getString(2)));
    }
    //Now add the data to a listview using a custom ListAdapter
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list, list);
    mMyListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
    return view;
}

/**
 * Example of CustomObjectClass
 **/
public class CustomObjectClass {
    private String nom;
    private String numero;

    public CustomObjectClass(String nom, String numero) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    //Create your getter and setter methods below
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample. I have shown a list of area on a fragment using customer adapter

```
  public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

private Button btnApply;
private ListView listArea;
    ArrayList<String> AreaArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
    savedInstanceState){
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);//fragment_one layout is the layout for first tab in filter

        listArea=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listArea);

    AreaArrayList.add("area1");
    AreaArrayList.add("area2");

            AreaListAdapter myOrderAdapter = new AreaListAdapter(getActivity(), AreaArrayList);
            listArea.setAdapter(myOrderAdapter);
        return view;
}


//adapter for the listview
public class AreaListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> AreaList;

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AreaListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> AreaArrayList) {
        this.context = context;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (AreaArrayList != null) {

            this.AreaList = AreaArrayList;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AreaList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return AreaList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int value;
        View areaRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.area_filter_list_item, null);

        TextView tvAreaFilter = (TextView) areaRow.findViewById(R.id.tvAreaFilter); //To set name of menu item, for example Corn Soup

        tvAreaFilter.setText(AreaList.get(position));


        //row onClickListener
        areaRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        return areaRow;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Comment: If you can help me here is the project url [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yu93eodsntnnjd4/AAAWo6N0dfc-rLUdUpolXyW2a?dl=0] listadmin is the class where I want to display my list

Comment: @Fanomezantsoa I can only provide you a sample. You have to make that work for your project. You cant expect people to code your project

Comment: I've been trying for a week and nothing works, I think I'll leave and make a list in an activity is better because the fragment I really do not find and I'm late to make my project then. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have used custom `listView` for Fragments in my sample project , You can check out my whole project [here](https://github.com/omardhanish/BloodBankAppLifeDrops)  , Here is [link](https://github.com/omardhanish/BloodBankAppLifeDrops/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/hackathonbloodapp/UpdateLayoutActivityFragment.java) for java file where I implement the     `custom ListView` .